# API для доступа к часам в Android

Tags: java, android, время, события

Пишу свой будильник. Контролы накидал, но как работает основной механизм не представляю - как при наступлении определенного времени проигрывать мелодию или вызывать вибрацию? Как называется это событие (event)?

Comment: думаю что если вас хватило только на то чтобы накидать контролы то куда то в глубь лезть без теории не стоит. Почитайте как нибудь умных книжек, на русском языке к сожалению таких нет, но зато есть ресурс habrahabr. Там много чего полезного

Comment: Голощапов А. Л. - Google Android программирование для мобильных устройств - 2011

Comment: Вообще, книг по андроиду на русском уже более чем достаточно!У меня лично 4. Озон поможет. Советую книгу Рето Мейера Андроид 2.Разработка приложений и Андроид за 24 часа, хотя последняя специфичная.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ссылка на готовый alarm: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/index.html#Alarm
чтобы проиграть mp3:

```
mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw./*your ringtone here*/);
mediaPlayer.start();
```

Comment: отлично, спасибо!